# LWC Datatable pagination sometimes returns 0 records

Tags: lightning-web-components, soql, pagination

I have a custom LWC datatable (basically extended to support an image column of thumbnails) in which I've also implemented pagination, which is achieved through use of SOQL OFFSET.

Given a page size limit of 10 and 303 records, I use the following JS to calculate the offset for the last page (tied to a Last button)

```
this.offSet = Math.floor(this.totalRows / this.limit) * this.limit;
```

and for most of the time it works, but sometimes I get a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%20jargon%2C%20a,one%20attempts%20to%20study%20it.) where the last button does not go to the last page of the dataset.

Writing out some `console.log` I can see that the returned dataset is not null, but is empty.  At first I thought this could be down to cases where offset = total record count, but I've *intermittently* reproduced it for record counts of 323 records for example - in that scenario I'd expect a last page of the odd 3 records.

For reference, once the JS determines the offset, it calls a `fetchRecords` method, which before parsing the data into a renderable format, calls back to an `import`ed Apex method with the required params

```
getLeadImageList({department: this.department, recordlimit: this.limit, offset: this.offSet})
```

and in turn, that Apex runs the following SOQL

```
List<Lead> leadList = [SELECT Id, Rating, Priority__c, Name, Status,Lead_Department__c,
                Seller_Products__c, Owner.Alias, Type__c, CreatedDate, Lead_Source_Detail__c,
                Response_Time__c, First_Email_Date__c, Last_Customer_Email_Date__c, No_of_Calls__c,
                HasOptedOutOfEmail, First_Call_Date__c, Last_Call__c
                FROM Lead
                WHERE Id IN :recordIDs
                ORDER BY CreatedDate
                LIMIT :recordlimit OFFSET :offset];
```

Console output from logging when I hit the Last button - note the empty data

[image]

Comment: Is the method set as cacheable? Are users messing your data while you're running these queries? Any other hints you can think of that might help us? I've always used pure client-side caching to avoid this problem (e.g. query all records for just their Id values, then load the remaining fields on demand by querying on Id).

Comment: Cachable - true, Users changing data - true

Comment: There's actually a couple of queries in play - one gets the records from one object (Lead) the other gets the associated thumbnails from a custom object, by LeadId

Comment: Using `OFFSET` is flawed because it is capped at 2000. Yeah, sure, that's a lot of pages if the page size is 10, but still it isn't scalable and guarantees you cannot allow the user access to all records if you have more than 2000+pageSize of them.

Comment: Understood and I've not been under any illusions on that, but its been agreed an acceptable risk - this particular custom datatable is essentially a highly filtered listview (date range constraints, field value constraints) on a rapidly evolving dataset of leads they're actively working.  For a more generalised view on Leads, they know to use the standard listview capabilities of the Leads tab

Comment: and page size is an admin-configurable parameter on the LWC, just in case

Comment: I would think that @sfdcfox is on to something around concurrent updates to the dataset. I wonder if you should ensure you get back the current total number each time to ensure you track that max pages appropriately, adjusting the query for an out-of-bounds offset before doing it, to return the "real" last page (if you don't want to hold the whole list client-side).